# what's the usage of "then" in the sentence below?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

the context:

As the children walked home, they saw a pretty tree.

> A: "Oh, what a pretty tree!"
>
> B: "**Then** stay away from it!!!!"
>
> A: "No, you're not gonna start again! This time it does not belong to the Sorceress!"
>
> B: NO!!! Don't climb that tree, don't eat the fruits!!!
>
> A: Who do you think you are? You're not our chief.
>
> B: NO!!!!!...

(he told them to leave it alone, but they didn't listen. They climbed up into its branches which then snapped shut, trapping them. The tree ran off through the forest).

I looked it up in the dictionary.
In Russian the word "then" means "тогда", "затем", "потом" (= next, at that time, in that case). That's why I don't get its usage in the given context.

Comment: An important part of the story seems to be missing. B is saying that the tree is dangerous **because** it is pretty (*then* is used to draw a conclusion). But we don't know why B is so suspicious of pretty things. --  BTW, is "gonna" the actual quote?

Comment: The Children must listen to B beacuse he is very wise.  They were told to do what he tells them, if they don't want to be eaten by the Sorceress.

Comment: But B is too small to save anybody so they don't listen. he annoys them

Comment: That's not the point. The question is what does B know to make him suspicious. If we weren't told that in the preceding part, then his behavior doesn't make sense to us. As [noted by others](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/470256/whats-the-usage-of-then-in-the-sentence-below?noredirect=1#comment1135524_470268), too.

Comment: Ok. The tree is suspicious because it grows on the surface of the ground. Its roots grows out from the main trunk so it looks like tentacles = legs. But the children think that as long as they don't eat the FRUITS there's no danger.

Comment: Could you explain what's wrong with "gonna"?

Comment: [shrug] You asked about the meaning of "then". B uses "then" to draw inference from "pretty", not from anything else. He says "**if** the tree is pretty, **then** stay away from it."

Comment: "Gonna" is very informal, some say non-standard. In quoted speech, it is often used to indicate that the speaker is uneducated.

Comment: It's *тогда*, Sofya. *Затем* and *потом* really make no sense here, so I'm not quite sure why you're even considering them. For that matter, *тогда* only works in the meaning "for that reason, with that in mind", but not in the meaning "at that time". All that said, you'd not necessarily use *тогда*, either. A much better translation is *вот и*. Вот и не трогайте его/оставьте его в покое/отойдите. (In other contexts, you could also go with *ну так и*, but I feel like in this one *вот и* is the superior of the two.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usage of "then" in this example is most closely related to your Russian dictionary's "in that case," or "because of that [reason]."

> "Oh, what a pretty tree! We've never seen anything like it!"
>
> "**Then** [because it's dangerous, you should] stay away from it!"

(Two things should be taken into account when seeking to understand grammar in any literature; namely:

a) an author's intentions and creative liberties

b) the time period in which the work was published, since grammar and style tend to be fluid concepts.

Comment: they must stay away from it because it is dangerous.  "We've never seen anything like it!" is unnecessary

Comment: There you go. Without the rest of the story, I wasn't sure the of the [reason]. So insert it into "because of that [reason]" and you have the same construction.

Comment: They climbed up into its branches which then snapped shut, trapping them. The tree ran off through the forest - it is the reason.

Comment: A's next speech implies that they had had a previous bad experience with a 'pretty tree', so B is warning that this similar tree may be dangerous too.

Answer (score 1):

"Then" can be used to mean "therefore". See meaning (3) listed at Oxford Dictionaries.

> 3 In that case; therefore.
>
> ‘if you do what I tell you, then there's nothing to worry about’

[Then (Oxford)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/then)